# Command-line website screenshot tool

Tags: monitoring

I want a command-line website screenshot tool so I can check the status/appearance of various websites. If possible, I'd want a tool that works on GNU/Linux and can be automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://browsershots.org/.  The source is available at http://code.google.com/p/browsershots/.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page: http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-ubuntu-linux

Gives you a few options when you scroll down a bit

Answer (score 0):

See https://browshot.com/api/documentation#simple There is an example with wget on the Browshot blog: http://blog.browshot.com/2012/01/api-14-simple-request.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and using **[rasterize.js](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)** to take screenshots of web pages.

**Example:**

```
phantomjs rasterize.js https://www.google.com/ screenshot.png
```

This is an especially attractive solution for developers who are developing with server-side JavaScript.

You can view the source code for rasterize.js here:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

Comment: It's possible to do this with Firefox and Chrome directly now, AFAIK