# A script that would create snapshots of web pages

Tags: looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Command-line website screenshot tool](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/command-line-website-screenshot-tool)

I have a list of websites that I need the "screenshot" of.  Is there a script for any browser that could do that?

Comment: Are these websites yours? Or someone else's?

Comment: They're not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://browsershots.org/ for a variety of all different browsers.